# Automatic Link conversion with preg_replace - but without last bracket, period and comma

Tags: php, preg-replace

The php q2a software www.question2answer.org parses links in text with the following preg_replace:

```
function qa_html_convert_urls($html, $newwindow=false) {
    return substr(preg_replace('/([^A-Za-z0-9])((http|https|ftp):\/\/([^\s&<>"\'\.])+\.([^\s&<>"\']|&amp;)+)/i', '\1<A HREF="\2" '.($newwindow ? ' target="_blank"' : '').'>\2</A>', ' '.$html.' '), 1, -1);
}
```

The only problem is that text such as "look here http://www.mydomain.com/." will link like `https://www.mydomain.com/.` or "look here (http://www.mydomain.com/)" will link `http://www.mydomain.com/)` the last char (period, comma or bracket) gets part of the link. And breaks the correct link.

Could you provide a solution for this issue?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: :) brute solution `substr_replace(qa_html_convert_urls($html, $newwindow), "", -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution is:

```
function qa_html_convert_urls($html, $newwindow=false) {
    return substr(preg_replace('/([^A-Za-z0-9])((http|https|ftp):\/\/([^\s&<>\(\)\[\]"\'\.])+\.([^\s&<>\(\)\[\]"\']|&amp;)+)/i', '\1<a href="\2" '.($newwindow ? ' target="_blank"' : '').'>\2</a>', ' '.$html.' '), 1, -1);`
}
```

Thanks and credits to [gidgreen](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/29015/improving-the-link-converter-dont-add-to-the-link?show=30374#a30374).